# C# Convert String plus to real plus

Tags: c#, string

i would like to know if there is a way to conver a string + to a real plus.
Example

```
string bla = "4+2";
```

i would like to reach, `4 + 2 = 6`

Thanks!

Comment: Of course there's a way - what do you think a compiler does?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using System.Data; //refference for DataTable 

string bla = "4+2";
object value = new DataTable().Compute(bla , null);
string res=value.ToString();//res=6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compile the expression and evaluate it at runtime. take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3988/Evaluating-Mathematical-Expressions-by-Compiling-C

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following Code**

```
string bla = "4+2";
Expression exp = new Expression(bla);
Console.write(exp.Evaluate());
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Int32 Number1; 
Int32 Number2;
String Result = Convert.ToString(Number1+Number2);
```